# An error occurred while executing doInBackground() Android AsyncTask error

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, wear-os, android-wear-data-api

Here is my code:

```
public void button_sendMessage(){
  new SendPhoneTask().execute();
}

public class SendPhoneTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
  @Override
  protected Void doInBackground(Void... args) {
    Collection<String> nodes = getNodes();
    for (String node : nodes) {
      sendDataMessage(node);
    }
    return null;
  }
}

private Collection<String> getNodes() {
  HashSet<String> results = new HashSet<>();
  NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult nodes = Wearable.NodeApi
                                         .getConnectedNodes(mGoogleApiClient).await();

  for (Node node : nodes.getNodes()) {
    results.add(node.getId());
  }

  return results;
}
```

I'm trying to send a message from my phone to my android wear device. But error occurs.
What is wrong with my code?

Comment: what is your error or do i need to go through all to find it for you? no gods powers here

Comment: it is a FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
                                                                                Process: com.example.jameschee.babystat, PID: 20595
                                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()

Comment: andCaused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Comment: where is ur sendDataMessage(); method ? 
May be you are trying to change something in main UI using doInBackground,which you cannot do  , full class might useful to solve the issue

Comment: private void sendDataMessage(String node) {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        Toast succeed = Toast.makeText(context,"succeed2",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        succeed.show();

Comment: Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage(
                mGoogleApiClient, node, SEND_DATA, new byte[0]).setResultCallback(
                new ResultCallback<MessageApi.SendMessageResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(MessageApi.SendMessageResult sendMessageResult) {
                        if (!sendMessageResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {

Comment: Log.e(TAG, "Failed to send message with status code: "
                                    + sendMessageResult.getStatus().getStatusCode());
                            Context context = getApplicationContext();
                            Toast succeed = Toast.makeText(context,"crashed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            succeed.show();

Comment: this is my send message method

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add error and description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

Move the toast inside

If `fragment` then use

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable (

  // toast
```

If `Activity` then use

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable 

  // toast
```

Hope this helps